# How this will work... npm with index.js and index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, npm

Is it possible to start your application with npm. In my application i just want one script file and one html file. I have gone through various sites but everyone has mentione to add node.js with express.

I want to do it without using express. I want the html page should load automatically once i do npm start.
My files would be

```
-package.json
-index.js
-home.html
```

Is there way to do this ? thanks in advance.

Comment: [`npm start`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-start) runs a predefined command specified in the "start" property of a package's "scripts" object. It won't magically start any server. Moreover, it's also not clear what you mean by loading the html automatically. You do not need node to open an html file locally.

Comment: What is `index.js` is that a client-side script loaded from `home.html` or is is a server-side script that e.g. creates a webserver and is required to send the `home.html` file? What do you men with `I want the html page should load automatically`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you index.js in the application.

```
{
  "name": "test1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index"
  }
}
```

If you want it to be served as a file you need to add a webserver that starts but I think that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

you can use live-server add it to pakage.json in the terminal .write this:`npm install -g live-server` then write live-server in the terminal it will load your page in the localhost